# Errors running make on wifi kernel module

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I was trying to solve my wifi connectivity problems using the instructions given [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/389372/72576).

When I try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git 
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723be
cd rtl8723be
make
```

I get the following error message:

```
~/rtl8723be/regd.c: in function ‘_rtl_reg_apply_beaconing_flags’:
~/rtl8723be/regd.c:200:20: error： ‘IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IR’ undeclared(first used in this function)
~/rtl8723be/regd.c:200:20: note： every undeclared identifier reported only once in the function
~/rtl8723be/regd.c: in function‘_rtl_reg_apply_active_scan_flags’:
~/rtl8723be/regd.c:237:19: error： ‘IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IR’undeclared(first used in this function)
~/rtl8723be/regd.c: in function‘_rtl_reg_apply_radar_flags’:
~/rtl8723be/regd.c:312:8: error： ‘IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IR’undeclared(first used in this function)
~/rtl8723be/regd.c: in function‘_rtl_regd_init_wiphy’:
~/rtl8723be/regd.c:410:18: error： ‘REGULATORY_CUSTOM_REG’undeclared(first used in this function)
~/rtl8723be/regd.c:411:19: error： ‘REGULATORY_STRICT_REG’undeclared(first used in this function)
~/rtl8723be/regd.c:412:19: error： ‘REGULATORY_DISABLE_BEACON_HINTS’undeclared(first used in this function)
make[2]: *** [/home/science/wifi/rtl8723be/regd.o] error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/science/wifi/rtl8723be] error 2
make[1]:leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-36-generic'
make: *** [all] error 2
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Thank Jobin to take a lot of time to format the text!I am a newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

The most recent version has been modified to correctly compile on kernel version 3.14; you are using 3.8.0-36. It is necessary to get an earlier version of the package. Please open a terminal and try:

```
cd rtl8723be
make clean
git checkout 604aa9058fb9e5bb1cf571c99989d081f8fc8b9
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

I believe it will make without errors but with, perhaps, a few warnings.

Comment: Oh,yeah!It really works.When making,there are no any warnings and errors.Now,the laptop can connect the wifi!Thanks a lot.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful,please accept it. Also, remember you will need to re-compile after a newer kernel version is installed by Update Manager.