# Wifi does not work Ubuntu 12LTS Lenovo S540

Tags: wireless, lenovo

When i was installing ubuntu Wifi worked without setting up anything. But once the installation is completed now I cannot connect to Wifi any more. The drop down says "not enabled" for the wifi option? How can I fix this?

here is what i get in " ifconfig -a"
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:1a:06:c3:xx:xx
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
wwan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:28:1a:75:aa:78

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer here so we may have the information to help you.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/389268/no-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-13-10 fixed the wifi problem i had

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type the following commands:

```
rfkill unblock wifi
nmcli nm wifi on
```

It should re enable the Wifi interface.

Comment: i typed both commands, no errors or anything. but nothing changers. do i need to reboot?

Comment: Before rebooting, try the following command to see if it's not hardware blocked: `rfkill list wifi`

Comment: nothing returns from that

Comment: It could be an hw issue, visit: http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-Edge-S-series/New-S540-wifi-driver-problem/td-p/1374479