# No wifi with Lenovo E540

Tags: wireless, lenovo

Hei,

I have the same problem as in [No wifi connection on Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/389268/no-wifi-connection-on-ubuntu-13-10), but can't comment on it because of missing reputations (I'm new to the forum). That's why I open a new question. I tried to use the solution suggested by chilli555 but get an error when executing the `make` command:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/build M=/home/fe/rtl8723be modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic'
CC [M]  /home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.o
In file included from /home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c:31:0:
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c: In function ‘_rtl_reg_apply_beaconing_flags’:
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.h:37:32: error: ‘IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
#define IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IBSS IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IR
                            ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c:200:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IBSS’
  ch->flags &= ~IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IBSS;
                ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.h:37:32: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
#define IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IBSS IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IR
                            ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c:200:20: note: in expansion of macro ‘IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IBSS’
  ch->flags &= ~IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IBSS;
                ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c: In function ‘_rtl_reg_apply_active_scan_flags’:
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.h:34:37: error: ‘IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
#define IEEE80211_CHAN_PASSIVE_SCAN IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IR
                                 ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c:237:19: note: in expansion of macro ‘IEEE80211_CHAN_PASSIVE_SCAN’
if (ch->flags & IEEE80211_CHAN_PASSIVE_SCAN)
               ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c: In function ‘_rtl_reg_apply_radar_flags’:
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.h:37:32: error: ‘IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IR’ undeclared (first use in this function)
#define IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IBSS IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IR
                            ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c:312:8: note: in expansion of macro ‘IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IBSS’
    IEEE80211_CHAN_NO_IBSS |
    ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c: In function ‘_rtl_regd_init_wiphy’:
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.h:40:38: error: ‘REGULATORY_CUSTOM_REG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
#define WIPHY_FLAG_CUSTOM_REGULATORY REGULATORY_CUSTOM_REG
                                  ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c:410:18: note: in expansion of macro ‘WIPHY_FLAG_CUSTOM_REGULATORY’
wiphy->flags |= WIPHY_FLAG_CUSTOM_REGULATORY;
              ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.h:43:38: error: ‘REGULATORY_STRICT_REG’ undeclared (first use in this function)
#define WIPHY_FLAG_STRICT_REGULATORY REGULATORY_STRICT_REG
                                  ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c:411:19: note: in expansion of macro ‘WIPHY_FLAG_STRICT_REGULATORY’
wiphy->flags &= ~WIPHY_FLAG_STRICT_REGULATORY;
               ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.h:46:41: error: ‘REGULATORY_DISABLE_BEACON_HINTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
#define WIPHY_FLAG_DISABLE_BEACON_HINTS REGULATORY_DISABLE_BEACON_HINTS
                                     ^
/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.c:412:19: note: in expansion of macro ‘WIPHY_FLAG_DISABLE_BEACON_HINTS’
wiphy->flags &= ~WIPHY_FLAG_DISABLE_BEACON_HINTS;
               ^
make[2]: *** [/home/fe/rtl8723be/regd.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/fe/rtl8723be] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-35-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2`
```

Pointy commented that another post worked for him, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The module rtl8723be is native in Ubuntu 14.04. If it isn't working as expected, there is something else wrong. Try to load it and see if there is an error or warning:

```
sudo modprobe rtl8723be
```

If there is no apparent error, check the log:

```
dmesg | grep rtl
```

If you find that you are missing firmware, you can get it with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware
```

If it is some other issue, please add the *dmesg* listings to your question and we'll proceed.